# Run ALAssetLibrary Block on Separate Thread

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks, nsthread

I am planning to get/add all the photo Library Image URLs into an NSMutableArray on a separate thread without disturbing the execution of program or main thread.

I need to do the process on application background while other operations are going on.

So I wrote the code below on my App Delegate Class **"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"** Delegate and also the ViewDidLoad function of my View Controller Class.

However the other features are not working while the ALAsset block is executing.

But the method **"crcGeneration"** is working without disturbing other features. As one can see in the code below, I called the method **"crcGeneration"** inside the ALAsset Block, in the same thread, after got all the Photo Library URLs.

Can any one tell me a good way to resolve the issue?

OnViewDidLoad:

```
//Calling the getAllURLofPhotLibraryImages Function on a seperate Thread.
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(getAllURLofPhotLibraryImages) toTarget:self withObject:nil];


Function for Getting all image URL's of PhotoLibrary.
**-(void)getAllURLofPhotLibraryImages**
{
   urlStoreArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];     //global array


      void (^assetEnumerator)(struct ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
      {
           if(result != NULL)
               {

                // Here storing the asset's image URL's in NSMutablearray urlStoreArr
                NSURL *url = [[result defaultRepresentation] url];
                [urlStoreArray addObject:url];                
          }

      };

      void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(struct ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
      {

           if(group != nil)
           {
                [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
           }
           else
           {       

               **[self crcGeneration];**   //Genearting CRC for PhotoLibrary Images using urlStoreArray after got all the Photo Library URL's .
           }

      };
 ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
  [assetslibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll       usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator   failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {        NSLog(@"Failure" );

     }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the asset URL like this:

```
NSURL *url = [result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyAssetURL];
```

The implementation of -defaultRepresentation is probably dispatching synchronously onto the main queue.